# Signing in via Google account does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, google-account

Does anyone know how to fix this? Everything works on the emulator:

[image]

But not on a real device:

[image]

I use this package to log in to my account through Google: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_oauth_google

Here is the code to sign in:

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
 final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await 
 GoogleSignIn().signIn();

 final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
    await googleUser?.authentication;

 final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
   accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
   idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
 );

 return await 
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could be related to SHA1 key. Did you configurated it?

Here the official documentation' screen with steps to follow:
[image]

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#ios+-and-android